# Put inline JavaScript in the head

Tags: javascript

The following code works:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img
{
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/Css/klematis.jpg" width="150" height="113" alt="klematis"
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40" />

<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/Css/klematis2.jpg" width="150" height="113" alt="klematis"
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40" />

</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is you have to repeat the inline JavaScript for all img tags. I tried to put the script in the head to no avail:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img
{
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getElements()
  {
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  x.style.opacity=1; x.filters.alpha.opacity=100;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/Css/klematis.jpg" width="150" height="113" alt="klematis"
onmouseover="getElements()"
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40" />

<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/Css/klematis2.jpg" width="150" height="113" alt="klematis"
onmouseover="getElements()"
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40" />

</body>
</html>
```

Everything seems right to me, but it doesn't work.

Many thanks for any help!

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection (which is a lot like an array), not an HTMLElementNode. Its members have a `style` property, but it doesn't have one of its own, and you can't distinguish the element on which the event happened from any other.

A step in the right direction would be:

```
function makeSolid(element) {
  element.style.opacity=1; x.filters.alpha.opacity=100;
}
```

and then `onmouseover="makeSolid(this)"`

A further step in the right direction would be to use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and attach the events using JS instead of using intrinsic event attributes. Due to differences between browsers, using an [event handling library](http://microjs.com/#events) to iron out the differences would be wise.

Since this depends on JS, the * initial* styling should be withheld until JS is confirmed to be on. Setting `document.body.className = 'js'` and then using `.js ...` as a descendent selector in each CSS ruleset is a popular way to do this.

Since this appears to be simply presentational, a further improvement would be to forget about JavaScript entirely and just do it using CSS:

```
img {
  opacity:0.4;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}

img:hover {
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: The CSS approach is the best! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference to the element into the function, using `this`:

```
function getElements(x) {
   x.style.opacity=1; x.filters.alpha.opacity=100;
}
```

Called like this:

```
onmouseover="getElements(this)"
```